# Get Java object using C++ to call the Java method

Tags: java, android, c++, c, native

I am developing in native and Java code for Android.

I plan to invoke a Java listener based on a C/C++ code. The idea is the C/C++ code call a method that actually invoke the Java Listener.

The C/C++ code is as follow. I can call the Java method using code below: the first code block is initiating the methodid and class inside JNI_OnLoad

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("com/example/crowdlogic/NativeManager");
    dataClassHandle = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
    if (dataClassHandle == NULL) LOGI("dataClassHandle null");
    LOGI("init dataUpdateHandle");
    dataUpdateHandle = env->GetMethodID(dataClassHandle, "dataUpdate", "(I)V");
    if (dataUpdateHandle == NULL) LOGI("dataUpdateHandle null");

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Next codeblock is actually calling it:

```
void sendCount(int totalCount) {
    jint jtotalCount = totalCount;
    jobject dataObjectHandle = env->NewObject(dataClassHandle, dataUpdateHandle);
    if (dataObjectHandle == NULL) LOGI("dataObjectHandle null");
    env->CallVoidMethod(dataObjectHandle, dataUpdateHandle, jtotalCount);
}
```

In the Java part, the dataUpdate method is actually called, but never invoke the listener. The listener is null. This is the Java listener class

```
public class NativeManager {

    private static final String TAG = "crowdlogic:native_manager";

    // all the listener stuff below
    public interface Listener {
        public void onDataUpdated(int totalCount);
    }

    private Listener mListener = null;

    public void registerListener (Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void dataUpdate(int totalCount) { // call this from JNI in C++ class
        // now notify if someone is interested.
        Log.i(TAG, "Data update in Java called");
        if (mListener != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "mListener not null");
        mListener.onDataUpdated(totalCount);
    }
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "mListener null"); // always come to this; the listener is null
    }
}
```

In my main activity, I have instantiated the listener (inside onCreate):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // start listener for data update
    mNativeMgr = new NativeManager();
    mNativeMgr.registerListener(this);
    mNativeMgr.dataUpdate(0);
    ...
}
```

I think this is because in the native part, instead of calling the instantiated Java listener object, I actually create a new one using the

```
jobject dataObjectHandle = env->NewObject(dataClassHandle, dataUpdateHandle);
```

inside void sendCount(int totalCount).

My question is, how can I get the instantiated Java object rather than create a new one, in the C/C++ code? Thanks guys, spent last 2 days on this already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of calling dynamic method, I make the Java method as static method and call it from C++ using CallStaticVoidMethod. Code example:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("com/example/crowdlogic/NativeManager");
    dataClassHandle = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
    dataUpdateHandle = env->GetStaticMethodID(dataClassHandle, "dataUpdate", "(I)V");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

The native function that calls the Java method:

```
void sendCount(int totalCount) {

jint jtotalCount = totalCount;
jobject dataObjectHandle = env->NewObject(dataClassHandle, dataUpdateHandle);
if (dataObjectHandle == NULL) LOGI("dataObjectHandle null");
LOGI("init CallVoidMethod");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(dataClassHandle, dataUpdateHandle, jtotalCount);
}
```

In Java, I declare the method as static method